# How do i insert in an insert command with mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a simple insert select which insert **_TABLE_B_** data in **_TABLE_A_** new row

```
INSERT INTO _TABLE_A_(_USERNAME_,_ID_) 
SELECT  _USERNAME_,_ID_ 
FROM _TABLE_B_
```

I want to insert a row in a table named **_TABLE_C_** each time i insert a row in **_TABLE_A**_ and add the current inserted **_TABLE_C_** id in **_TABLE_A_**.

i'll try to explain it in an other way :

```
INSERT INTO _TABLE_A_(_USERNAME_,_ID_,_FOREIGN_ID_) 
SELECT  B._USERNAME_,B._ID_,C._FOREIGN_ID_
FROM _TABLE_B_ AS B 
LEFT JOIN _TABLE_C_ AS C
#Insert a row in _TABLE_C_ to retrieve _FOREIGN_ID_...
```

I'm searching for a single minimal query which have the **INSERT SELECT** statement like mine because insert select can loop and i have to loop.

FYI : 
I'm in a stored procedure.
I also use prepared statements with dynamic data, and cursors is not suitable for dynamic data select...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

1. create a temporary table and add dynamic select statement which retrieve the primary keys (id)
2. declare a cursor and select this temporary table id ( variables doesn't work but temporary tables do )
3. execute statement to create temporary table
4. open the cursor and iterate the inserts

---

EXAMPLE

---

```
  BEGIN


    DECLARE isDone INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE fetchedmemberWhoWillReceiveMailId int;

    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM memberWhoWillReceiveMail;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET isDone = 1;
    SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

    SET @sexe     = VAR_sexe; 
    SET @event    = VAR_eventId;
    SET @subject = VAR_subject;
    SET @body     = VAR_body; 
    SET @to        = VAR_to; 
    SET @from  = VAR_from;
    SET @region    = VAR_region;
    SET @departement      = VAR_departement; 
    SET @age        = VAR_age;

    SET @baseSqlStatement =' CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE memberWhoWillReceiveMail SELECT e.id FROM TABLE_A as e LEFT JOIN TABLE_B AS a on a.member_id = e.id';

    SET @whereSqlStatement= 'WHERE e.is_visible = 1 AND e.member_group_id IN (10,11) ';

    IF (@region!='') THEN  
    SET @whereSqlStatement=  CONCAT(@whereSqlStatement,' AND region=',@region);
    END IF;

    IF (@event !=null ) THEN 
    SET @whereSqlStatement=  CONCAT(@whereSqlStatement,' AND m.event_id !=' ,@eventId); 
    END IF;

    IF (@sexe!=null ) THEN
    SET @whereSqlStatement=  CONCAT(@whereSqlStatement,' AND e.sexe=',@sexe); 
    END IF;

    SET @baseSqlStatement = CONCAT(@baseSqlStatement,@whereSqlStatement);

    START TRANSACTION;
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @baseSqlStatement;
    EXECUTE stmt1; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

    OPEN cur1; 
    FETCH cur1 INTO fetchedmemberWhoWillReceiveMailId; 
    WHILE NOT isDone DO
        INSERT INTO conversation(created_at,updated_at)VALUES(now(),now());
        INSERT INTO message(created_at,updated_at,from, to, uniqueID)   VALUES(now(),now(),@from,fetchedmemberWhoWillReceiveMailId,LAST_INSERT_ID() );
        FETCH cur1 INTO fetchedmemberWhoWillReceiveMailId; END WHILE; CLOSE cur1;

    COMMIT;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS memberWhoWillReceiveMail;

    END
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do all the INSERTs in _TABLE_C_ first and then join it in the INSERT _TABLE_A_ to get the appropriate foreign keys.

If that is not possible, I would use a cursor.

```
Cursor on _TABLE_B_ & Fetch

INSERT _TABLE_C_

INSERT _TABLE_A_ with Foreign_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Fetch next
```

Comment: ok no matter if it works, show me ;D 
remember i have to do the inserts at the same time to avoid corrupted data

Comment: What are your columns in _TABLE_C?

Comment: i see, but i cant use cursor, i use an insert select with a where with dynamic data passed to the stored procedure, the cursor will throw an error if i use my where with my variables, i read the mysql documentation about cursor, and i test it also.

Comment: _TABLE_C_ = ID, CREATED_AT, UPDATED_AT

Comment: Ok, and if you declare variables in your stored procedure to store a copy of your parameters and use the variables in your select-where, does it work? If not, je suis désolé, but unfortunately I don't have an answer for you.

Comment: The problem is not with my variables (my SP is working fine), i just want to insert while i insert, my variables can't let me use cursors.
Of course i know there is a difference on what i want and what i can do ;D
Thank you for your time Danny.